Can a countable union of subgroups of uncountable index in G be equal to G?
Let G be a group and $\{H_i\}_{i<\omega}$ be a countable family of subgroups of $G$, each of them of uncountable index. Can $G=\bigcup_{i<\omega} H_i$?

I would like someone to confirm but I tend to think that $G={+1,-1}^{\mathbb{N}}$ , with $H_i$ being each of the ${+1,-1}$ terms of the product, is a counterexample.

@EricBrier Their union is not a subgroup, and if by $F_i$ you call the subgroup generated by $H_1,\cdots,H_i$, then $\bigcup_{i\in\omega} F_i={+1,-1}^{\oplus \Bbb N}\subsetneqq G$.

Union of subgroups is indeed in general not a subgroup. The question is to know if union equals the whole group. In my example, it is stricly smaller than the whole group and it is not a subgroup.

@EricBrier Obviously there are instances where $\bigcup_{i\in \omega} H_i\ne G$: the question asks if there are instances where equality holds. There are no counterexamples to claims of existence.

You're right, I took question the wrong way. However, it has been closed in-between.

Consider $G=(\Bbb R^{\oplus\Bbb N},+)$, i.e. $G={f\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},:, \lvert {x\in\Bbb N,:, f(x)\ne 0}\rvert<\aleph_0}$ with componentwise sum, and call $H_n={f\in G,:, \forall x>n, f(x)=0}$. Then $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} H_n=G$ and $G/H_n\cong G$.
